# Callkit incoming call ui

Tags: ios, iphone, callkit

I am using call kit framework for calling and please help me
how to remove call kit ui when incoming call occurs during app in foreground and call in process, i am getting call kit ui in background.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: Hello Megha, Actually we don't need to remove callkit ui  when i found this same thing in whatsApp. So this is not an issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can check for app state before reporting a new incoming call to `CXProvider`. If you do not wish to use system incoming call screen when your app is in foreground, then give the `if` statement not to report new incoming call screen if the app is in foreground.

Example:

```
let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState

if state == .background {
    // background
    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(uuidString: call.callUUID)!, update: callUpdate) { error in /* */ }
}
```